# How to add multiple sender email addresses in WordPress and WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

I am trying to add multiple email addresses or change the email address where customer responses to order notifications are sent.

I have the WooCommerce configuration as follows:

```
WooCommerce => Settings => Emails => Email Sender Options => Sender Address:
```

Initially, in this configuration I had the following email: `soporte@mybusiness.com`

I have tried to add two different email addresses, separating them by a comma `("," )`, as follows:

`support@mybusiness.com, myemail@gmail.com`,

But this doesn't work.

When the user responds to the email that arrived to notify him that his order was received, his message is not sent and he receives the following notice:

Address not found
Your message has not been delivered to `support@mybusiness.commyemailgmail.com`
because the domain mybusiness.commyemailgmail.com was not found. Check that there are no typos or spaces required and try again.

This is displayed as you see it, the email addresses together.

I have asked professionals and they have suggested some function with php.
I have used some example but it doesn't work either.

```
function custom_change_reply_to_address( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Verificar si el correo electrónico es para notificar al cliente sobre el pedido completado
    if ( $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        // Cambiar las direcciones de correo a las que quieres que lleguen las respuestas del cliente
        $new_reply_to_emails = array(
            'correo1@tuempresa.com',
            'correo2@tuempresa.com',
            'correo3@tuempresa.com',
        );

        // Convertir el array de direcciones en una lista separada por comas
        $new_reply_to_email = implode( ',', $new_reply_to_emails );

        // Remover el "Reply-To" actual, si es que existe
        $headers = preg_replace( '/^Reply-To:/m', '', $headers );

        // Agregar la nueva lista de direcciones de correo al encabezado
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $new_reply_to_email\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_change_reply_to_address', 10, 3 );
```

How can I add two email addresses to this WooCommerce setup?
WooCommerce => Settings => Emails => Email Sender Options => Sender Address

Comment: _One_ email can not have _two_ senders. Sure, you could send the same email twice, once for each sender - but first of all, WooCommerce is probably not prepared to do this, and more importantly, you don't want the customer to receive _two_ confirmation mails. _"or change the email address where customer responses to order notifications are sent."_ - that can be done by specifying a `Reply-To` address, which appears to be what the above code is attempting to do. But we can't help you much based on nothing more than "doesn't work", that does not work for us as a problem description.

Comment: _"I don't quite understand what he means by "Reply-To"."_ - normally, when you click on "reply" in your email client, it will populate the "To:" field of the new email, with the sender address of the email you are replying to, the `From:` address. By also setting a `Reply-To` header you can change that behavior, so that the `To:` field will automatically be populate with that address (or addresses) instead.

Comment: _"to go to multiple senders. But I think I understand that's not possible"_ - you want them to go to multiple _recipients_ - the _sender_ here is your customer, they are the one replying to the email they received. And that _should_ be possible, `Reply-To` allows to specify multiple recipients. (Whether each mail client in existence also supports multiple address values in this field, might be a different question.)

Comment: Have you looked at the headers of one of those mails your system sends out with that code in use, and checked whether there was actually a `Reply-To` line in there now?

Comment: If you want your _outgoing_ email to reach more than one recipient, then you would need to add a `CC:` or `BCC:` header with those addresses (carbon copy/ blind carbon copy), not a `Reply-To`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood you. I want the outgoing mail from the "CLIENT" in response to notifications to reach various destinations. What files should I modify for this? I think this cannot be done from WooCommerce, it will be necessary to edit files

Comment: That should be possible using pretty much the same code, only adding `CC:` or `BCC:`, instead of `Reply-To:`. And the `preg_replace` line can likely be removed - that was used to remove the already existing `Reply-To:` header line (usually gets set to the same value, as `From:`, but a `CC:` or `BCC:` is not likely to have been set by default already.

Comment: Well, I'll study your answer carefully, I don't understand exactly what I should change. Maybe the translation that translate.google gives me is not entirely good

Comment: Remove this line`$headers = preg_replace( '/^Reply-To:/m', '', $headers );`, and change `$headers .= "Reply-To: $new_reply_to_email\r\n";` to `$headers .= "CC: $new_reply_to_email\r\n";`, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I made these changes, but the client's response still only arrives at the email address set in WooCommerce => Settings => Emails => Email Sender Options => Sender Address. I will try to do tests based on this, but I don't have much experience to correct it either.

Comment: I'd check the actual headers of such an email the customer received first of all, to see if any `CC:` header actually made it into there.

Comment: The response only from: 1 - From: Name-Of-The-Web + < email that there is from the sender in WooCommerce >/ 2- Reply to: Name-Of-The-Web + < email that there is from the sender > in WooCommerce / 3 - To: Client Email / 4 - Date: / 5 - Subject: / 6 - Sent by: What would the header be in this case?